# Print PDF Envelope for single contact

Tags: pdf, envelope

I am looking for a way to add an action or link that will automatically print(generate pdf) an envelope for a contact from the summary tab in civicrm. This would bypass the selection of a template. Any thoughts on a module or link i can use?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that comes to mind is to write an extension to do this. The only way to do it "out of the box" would be to utilize the Print PDF Letter option and utilize a template that would size to an envelope.